# How can I use stored procedure call in sails js?

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js

Currently I am working on building a project using sailsjs. I want to use stored procedure call in sailsjs controller. Any suggestions on how can I use that?

Comment: Do you use `Waterline`? If so, you should be able to execute `CALL` queries with [.query()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query) method.

Comment: Why do you want to use stored procedure call? Please specify the use case in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the SP using the `.query` waterline, like this:

```
        Model.query('CALL yourSP', function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(400);
            } else {
                res.send(result);
            }
        });
```

And if you are using parameters:

```
    example: function(req, res){

        var x = req.param('x');
        var y = req.param('y');

        Model.query('CALL yourSP("'+x+'","'+y+'") ', function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(400);
            } else {
                res.send(result);
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using parameters:

```
Model.query("call yourSP(?)",[email], function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("errerr", err);
      }
      console.log("results", results);
  });
```